# Can I copy UV map to many objects with the same and/or symmetrical topology?

Tags: uv

I made a shoe, which needed to fit 7 different characters. So I made a mirror object for another leg, and then copied resulting 2 boots 7 times and changed shape to fit the 7 characters. Then I found I have a problem in my UV map layout.

Is it possible to fix it once and then propagate it through all 14 objects, or I have to start again from 1 shoe?

Comment: Does `Ctrl+L` *> Transfer UV layouts* work?

Comment: @gandalf3, it does work for identical, thank you, I wish I could accept comment as an answer. And it worked for me for symmetrical objects as well.

Answer (score 4):

I used the [suggestion given by gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/can-i-copy-uv-map-to-many-objects-with-the-same-and-or-symmetrical-topology#comment7691_4899) and made it all work for my case. Here is the procedure:

1. I have 14 shoes objects with identical broken UV, 7 of them are mirrored (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> mesh mirroring).
2. I fix UV on one of the shoes
3. I go to its mirrored version of the fixed shoe, **flip normals** and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *-> Transfer UV layouts*. (If I do not flip normals transfer does not work right and resulting texture is a mess).
4. I flip normals on the mirrored object again. At this point one size of the shoes has right texture with correct UV map for both mirrored and not mirrored mesh.
5. I use mirrored mesh to transfer to all 7 mirrored sizes  by selecting all mirrored objects and selecting last the mirrored object with corrected UV and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *-> Transfer UV layouts*.
6. Repeat the same procedure for not mirrored 7 sizes.

Comment: I've asked a similar question here to get a solution, and I've finally figured out on my own how to fix this. In my case that was about to transfer uvs from one static character with the uvs done, to the same character mesh animated/rigged, whitout uvs.. CTRL+L gave as result a mess, so I've finally simply deleted the half of my static character, I deleted as well the half of my animated character, and this way I could transfer uvs properly. After that I just had to apply again a mirror modifier to get my full character...It seems transfer uvs has some troubles with overlapped uvs no!?

Comment: sounds like a good approach. The difference was that in my case I did not have mirror modifier, my other boot was made by applying mesh mirror Ctrl+M