# Can I transfer an already made UV to another object?

Tags: mesh, uv, objects

I've got two objects that are exactly the same, but with different UVs, is there any way to transfer the UV from one to another?

Comment: Try selecting them both, hitting `ctrl-L` and "tranfer UV maps"

Comment: I think that active object gives its map to the other selected objects, but I can never keep it straight

Comment: Just a heads up, this might be a duplicate

Comment: It IS a duplicate of this somehow: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/uv-coordinates-on-a-deformed-plane

Comment: @ajwood Post that as an answer

Comment: @Gonzou I don't think it's a duplicate. The answer might be the same, but my question was about "fixing" a UV map, while this one specifically asks about transferring them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transfer uvs from static mesh to the same rigged and animated mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4910/how-to-transfer-uvs-from-static-mesh-to-the-same-rigged-and-animated-mesh)

Comment: duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4910 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4899

Comment: @ajwood You're right!

Comment: I think you are looking for the copy paste UVs I hope this help you [copy paste uvs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Copy_Paste_UVs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I copy UV map to many objects with the same and/or symmetrical topology?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/can-i-copy-uv-map-to-many-objects-with-the-same-and-or-symmetrical-topology)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can select the two objects, and link their UV maps.

1. Select the "target" object
2. Select the "source" object (this needs to be the active object)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, "Transfer UV maps"

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the objects are not identical? I have a floating decal object attached to a parent, and I'd like to uv unwrap the decal so its verts get the same uvs as the nearest parents verts... so when I texture them both with the same material the decal would be seamless and invisible on top...

Comment: I have been looking for a way to copy coordinates for individual quads from one mesh to another. I can not find a way to retrieve or specify exact UV coordinate. Is the only solution to write a Python script?