# How to Copy & paste texture

Tags: texturing, materials

In the image i have 5 rock at one side and a single red mark rock. I have done uv mapping to the red mark rock. I want the texture of the red mark rock on all rest of the 5 rocks. I have applied the material to the 5 rocks but the texture not applied. Im in cycle render now. How to get the texture on rest of the rocks

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "How can I copy the UVs from the one rock to the others?"?

Comment: Are the other rocks uv-unwrapped, too?

Comment: @pycoder yes ur right i want to copy the uv from one rock to the others

Comment: @metaphor_set the red mark with texture that only single rock is uv unwrapped

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/can-i-transfer-an-already-made-uv-to-another-object

Comment: I have tried that but did not work

Comment: @atek If you try something and it doesn't work you have to say what you tried and what about it isn't working. You can use the [edit] link below your question to add more information. Remember, the more information you give the more likely people will be able to understand.

Comment: actually mean time i got the reply until i reply that ctrl+L did not work sorry if so i was late

Comment: i can do it manually only for 5 rocks but its for future if i have more mesh rocks maybe useful for others also