# How to fix a 3D scanned object with texture in Blender?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, sculpting

I have 3d scanned an object and imported it into Blender. The model has a texture as well as the mesh. The 3D scanner is not perfect, some holes and imperfections in the mesh have occurred.

How do I edit the mesh of the obj file and preserve the texture? I haven't found any videos or instructions on how to fix a mesh that already has texture.

Please let me know if anyone has done this before and has some advice.
Thank you!

Comment: There could be 2 approaches - fixing the scan and working with retopo of the scan. It can be wise to work on a scan first to close the holes etc. Then pin existing UV vertices except for new ones and unwrap. Note that if baking texture to lowpoly all errors will be on lowpoly as well. In some cases if errors are too big rebuilding the scan might be better option

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clean mesh out of your 3D scan you should first

Do a retopology of your 3D scan. Basicly treat it as if it were sculpted.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9NAv_q_wfU

If you plan of doing this more often think about buying Blender Retopo Tools: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZH8RJDr6pg

Here is a quick and dirty retopo guide for 3d scans:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbtWoJXbytM

Lastly transfer UV coordinates from your 3D scan to the new (retopo) mesh.
[Can I transfer an already made UV to another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/can-i-transfer-an-already-made-uv-to-another-object)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have the time for a detailed workflow description but these are the generic steps of my process:

1. Import obj (mesh A)
2. Duplicate (mesh B) and fix geometry scan artefacts (remove fixing glue or supports, close holes and smooth/flatten the surface where needed)
3. Generate a low poly topology (mesh C) from this fixed scan - I use quad remesher for speed and acceptable edge flow. Retopology can be done by hand in vanilla blender if you have the time.
4. Create UVs on mesh C
5. Add a subdivision modifier and confom (with SrinkWrap modifier) C to B to better get the original details
6. Bake textures and normals from B to C
7. Fix issues on the baked maps ( in Blender paint mode, Photoshop or better in Substance Painter)